# Disallow creating thread multiple times

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

In my windows message loop I am invoking a std::thread to calculate something (game-specific stuff). I wanted to disallow the loop to create a next thread until it has calculated what he had to calculate.  For now I am dealing with this that way:

```
if( !mIsCalculating ) {
    mIsCalculating = true;
    std::thread th( Test::method, this );
    th.detach();
}

void Test::method() {
    // ...
    mIsCalculating = false;
}
```

but I wonder whether there is an existing solution in the std library, like std::invokeWhenLastDone? ;-)

Comment: Without a lock, if this code will be called twice in the same time you might create 2 threads.
If you call this only from one specific thread it's not an issue.

Comment: std::invokeWhenLastDoneWhatExactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of spawning a new thread for each task, why not just form a few worker threads and then use `std:packaged_task` and `std::future` to concurrently calculate things without the overhead of spawning a new thread.

For instance:

```
class Calculator {
public:
    Calculator() : m_bDoneFlag( false ) {
        for( auto& thread : m_arrayThreads )
        {
            thread = std::thread( [this]{
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lockGuard( m_mutex, std::defer_lock );

                while( !m_bDoneFlag )
                {
                    lockGuard.lock();
                    m_condTaskWaiting.wait( lockGuard, [this]{ return !m_queueTasks.empty(); } );

                    std::packaged_task<void*()> packagedTask = std::move(m_queueTasks.front());
                    m_queueTasks.pop();

                    lockGuard.unlock();

                    // Execute task:
                    packagedTask();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    ~Calculator()
    {
        m_bDoneFlag = true;

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lockGuard( m_mutex );
        m_queueTasks.emplace( []{ std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds(100) ); return nullptr; } );
        m_queueTasks.emplace( []{ std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds(100) ); return nullptr; } );
        lockGuard.unlock();
        m_condTaskWaiting.notify_all();

        for( auto& thread : m_arrayThreads )
        {
            thread.join();
        }
    }

    std::future<void*>                          AddTask( std::function<void*()> funcToAdd )
    {
        std::packaged_task<void*()> packagedTask( funcToAdd );
        std::future<void*> future = packagedTask.get_future();

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lockGuard( m_mutex );
        m_queueTasks.emplace( std::move(packagedTask) );
        lockGuard.unlock();
        m_condTaskWaiting.notify_one();

        return future;
    }

private:
    std::mutex                                  m_mutex;
    std::array<std::thread, 2>                  m_arrayThreads;
    std::queue<std::packaged_task<void*()>>     m_queueTasks;
    std::condition_variable                     m_condTaskWaiting;
    std::atomic<bool>                           m_bDoneFlag;
};
```

You can then use this like so:

```
int main()
{
    Calculator myCalc;

    std::future<void*> future1 = myCalc.AddTask( []{ std::string* pszTest = new std::string("Test String"); return pszTest; } );
    std::future<void*> future2 = myCalc.AddTask( []{ std::complex<float>* pcmplxTest = new std::complex<float>( 5.0f, 10.5f ); return pcmplxTest; } );

    std::string* pszTest = reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(future1.get());
    std::complex<float>* pcmplxTest = reinterpret_cast<std::complex<float>*>(future2.get());

    std::cout << *pszTest << " and " << *pcmplxTest << std::endl;

    delete pszTest;
    delete pcmplxTest;

    return 0;
}
```

Obviously this doesn't have the type-safety we'd want, and you can improve type-safety significantly if you can narrow down the type of return value that you will always need to prevent having to return a pointer to `void`.

Comment: `AddTask` and `~Calculator` both access `m_queueTasks` without `m_mutex` held, resulting in a data race.

Comment: Probably yet another case of the OP reading some moronic 'Intro to Threads' site/page, (for they are legion), that starts off 'To use threads, you have to continually create them and wait for them to terminate'.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know such a method does not exist.
However, you can solve your problem by letting a single thread running forever and managing the repetitions you need inside Test::Method.
When a new calculation is needed, the main loop could notify Test::Method by using a std::condition_variable.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, `mIsCalculating` should be an atomic value, so that you don't get problems with using a non-atomic variable in two different threads. Aside from that and assuming this is used in the "UI thread", it would only be called from one thread, so should be acceptable.

There are also several alternative solutions, such as have a single thread that runs forever and feed the data into a pipe, messagequeue or using an event to signal "more work available, and a similar event to for "here's the result".